# Godot 4 full text search

Tags: godot, gdscript

How can i made full text search in godot

[vboxcontainer with link buttons](https://i.stack.imgur.com/exCTR.png)

I created a "line edit" and in the node specified "text_changed" in "vboxcontainer"
Please tell me how should I proceed?